# Automatically extract all audio tracks from movie files in OS X or Bash?

Tags: video, audio, media

I'd like to extract the audio out of any video file (*not* dvds).

I have easy access to OS X and Bash and I'm very comfortable with both.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links at:

http://muhdzamri.blogspot.com/2007/06/converting-video-and-extracting-audio.html

and

http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/229/extract-audio-from-video-or-online-stream/

should help you do this.

Answer (score 4):

The command-line tool ffmpeg can do this.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:a -c copy output.m4a
```

The above will work for MPEG audio (MP3, AAC), and AC3 and ALAC audio. If it *is* MP3 audio, you'd be better off using `output.mp3`; if it's FLAC or Vorbis, use `output.ogg`.

If you want to extract any audio to a fairly high-quality MP3, use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:a -c libmp3lame -q:a 2 output.mp3
```

If your video uses more than one audio track (different languages, for example) you can select a single audio track with: `-map 0:a:0`to select the first audio only, `-map 0:a:1` to select the second audio track, and so on.